# Can't run PSQL scripts from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, postgresql

I can't seem to run PSQL script files from my Ubuntu terminal.
Specifically, when I run `./populate_ppima_db.sh melon melon` I get the following output:

```
Insert Basic Data
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "melon"
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "melon"
Insert PPIMA data
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "melon"
```

I am at a loss. What do I need to do to be able to run `PSQL` scripts from my terminal with my user?

Here's my `pg_hba.conf` file:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             all                                     md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, after running the following command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d postgres -c "alter user melon with password 'melon'"
```

And changing the following lines on my `pg_hba.conf` file from

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
```

to

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     password
```

the script now runs correctly.

If I am to be completely honest I cannot explain why, but this did fix my problem.

Comment: If anyone can offer an explanation as to why the above worked I'll gladly include in my answer or use yours as the correct answer.

Comment: As per [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/auth-methods.html#AUTH-PASSWORD), when password is null `password` and `md5` authentication methods will fail.

Comment: To use PostgreSQL effectively, you will sooner or later need to understand the `pg_hba.conf` file. See [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). The key to your initial problem was "Peer authentication failed". The authentication method is controlled in `pg_hba.conf`.